# Using XMSS with Blake2

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

Since XMSS only requires a 2nd preimage resistant hash function, is using Blake2 in XMSS possible? It is not in standard, but Blake2 seems to be faster than SHA256

Comment: Are you asking "possible" in the sense of possible without hurting security, or in the sense of possible without hurting interoperability?

Comment: Obvious question: if you care about performance, why aren't you considering LMS?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible, but the standard needs some amendment to make it formal.

It's interesting to know that, [KangarooTwelve](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-irtf-cfrg-kangarootwelve/) is even faster, but nonetheless, **not yet formallized**.

Also that NIST intends approve SHAKE XOFs as MGF in RSA in [FIPS 186-5](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.186-5-draft), but **not yet included in PKCS#1** (Although, it had been included in [RFC-8692](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8692))